# How to place a screen control in the home screen that will be always visible

Tags: android

I need a screen control (possibly but not mandatory an app widget) that will seat
on Android's homescreen and will always be visible to the user - even when he scrolls the homescreen to the next page.

Please help me if any body have done this before.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only way you will be able to do this is if you implement your own Launcher.

The functionality that you're looking for, being able to place a static widget on every screen of the launcher regardless of how many screens they have, isn't currently available in Android, nor any of the launcher apps out there (Go launcher, ADW, Launcher pro etc) nor any of the versions of Android which have been rewritten by the phone manufacturers (HTC's Sense, Samsungs Touch Wiz etc)

It's a big job to write a Launcher yourself, but the stock Android Launcher code is available to play about with from https://android.googlesource.com.

Comment: Thanks Martyn
It seems very long and hard approach.Is there any way to place a static view on the home screen that will not scrolled?
Regards

Comment: No - I'm fairly certain that this isn't currently possible.  Have you looked at apps like Power Strip (https://market.android.com/details?id=mobi.intuitit.android.p.powerstrip)?  It is a launcher replacement app but it doesn't actually replace the launcher, instead it captures a double tap on the home button and provides extra functionality and lets a single home button press still take you to the normal launcher.  Could that be a possible way forward for you?